# Lightweight Rails 3 WYSIWYG editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, tinymce

As the title states, I'm looking for a lightweight Rails 3(.1) WYSIWYG editor.  I don't want to have to install a bunch of plugins, it should be through a Gem.  It doesn't have to be feature rich either (no need for image uploading, etc).

I've tried the 2 tinymce plugins on GitHub and none of them have really worked.  The frustration is that they do not seem to be built for Rails 3.1+.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give [wymeditor](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor) a try. Github uses it. It's pretty well maintaned, has lots of features (which can be excluded), and is just js file.

Here's the [official site](http://www.wymeditor.org/).